# Controlling the order of a C++ destructor and that of the object's ivars

Tags: c++, object

I have an object that manages a global resource and has several ivars (kinda auto objects) that each access that resource. When I destory the object I close the resource in it's destructor. Unfortunately, the ivars also access that resource once in their d-tors. Since ivar d-tors are called at the end of the object d-tor this obviously crashes.

My question is now: is it possible (and how) to determine the order of destruction (probably more like: can I make the ivar have their d-tors called before my object's d-tor ends)?

I can probably convert all the value ivars to reference ivars and delete them explicitely, but this has serious consequences on other parts, so I'd like to gauge the options I have to stay with my current value types.

Code example:

```
class A {
  A() { inc_ref_in_context(); }
  ~A() { dec_ref_in_context(); }
};

class Container {
  A _ivar1;
  A _ivar2;
  A _ivar3;
  ...
 ~Container() { release_context(); }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing wrong. The constructor/destructor pairing guarantee in C++ is pretty robust, not easily broken. Perhaps, instead of a broken DIY scheme, use standard library containers and/or smart pointers such as std::shared_ptr.

Comment: -1 Not real code. Please post a **complete** but minimal example, that one can copy and paste into an editor and compile. The code you have posted would not even compile without some corrections. It's impossible to say what errors are present in the real code.

Comment: If this is a skeleton of your code, then 2 things come up:
1. your container has objects variable of class A
2. You know how many variables u need.

U can create a template container (list, vector, map ) or  use a dynamically created memory with `new` for ivars. So in the destructor of Container class u can call the destructor of ivar before destroying the container.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, but my guess is you could move ownership of the shared resource to another member of `Container` declared before all the `A` objects.

Comment: @Cheersandhth., your comment doesn't help and neither does your downvote. It's a question that describes an idea, a principle, for which I'm looking for suggestions (and got very good ones).

Comment: @MikeLischke: I'm sorry that you're trolling. Or perhaps rep-point harvesting. Whatever -- non-sincere.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: In what way is this trolling? It describes a design problem, and asks how to fix it. You don't need compilable code to see that `~Container()` is called before `~A()`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: the bugs are unknowable without real code. you have chosen to *answer* this ill-defined question, recommending a kludge to hide the symptoms of the unknowable bugs, and the OP has chosen that as a solution. it sounds like you're both happy then, except for reacting a bit too caustically to a simple request for real code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The bug is that the resource is released before the "ivar" objects have finished using it, as clearly described in the question. There's no need for working code to understand that. My answer suggests how to manage the object's lifetime to fix the known bug, not to "hide the symptoms of the unknowable bugs".

Comment: @MikeSeymour: presumably you don't actually know what the bug is (if you did then you have access to the original code).. you state that the symptom, premature release, is the bug causing it. that's utter nonsense, and there's no other conclusion than that you're trying to confuse readers.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The description, and example code, are quite clear. The resource is released by `~Container()`; after that, each member is destroyed, calling `~A()`, which tries to access the resource. That is the bug; the solution is to defer releasing the resource until after the "ivar" things have finished with it. That's not "nonsense", that's how the C++ object model works.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: the OP's pseudo-code indicates that the resource is reference-counted. for correct code that is incompatible with your scenario- what you're saying is the bug, is just a symptom, of incorrect reference counting.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Which is why my first suggestion is to implement reference counting correctly; and failing that, to arrange to release the resource later. Perhaps you could read the question and answer before you continue trolling; in any case, I'm done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems odd that the "context" is reference-counted, but doesn't release itself when the reference count reaches zero. That might be the most robust solution.

Otherwise, you could release it in the destructor of a base class, or an extra member declared before the "ivar" members.

Comment: Excellent.  That was the required inspiration I needed. A base class makes a lot of sense (also for other stuff), so this is the way I went.

Answer (score 1):

Order of members initialization/destruction is also well defined, so as per aschepler's comment her's some code:

```
class A;

class B {
  ~B() { release_context(); }
};

class Container {
  B context;
  A _ivar1;
  A _ivar2;
  A _ivar3;
}
```

Comment: Just explaining this a bit more - the destructors are always called in the reverse order of the construction. The object's constructor is called after the constructors of its members, and therefore the object's destructor is called before the destructors of its members. This cannot be changed.   Further, the construction order of sub-objects must match the order they are in the class definition. So in this code the construction order must be `context, _ivar1, _ivar2, _ivar3, Container`, and the destruction order is the reverse of that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the resource be responsible for the ivars that access it?
e.g. add a method "get_new_ivar()" which creates and tracks all the ivars.

Then, in the destructor of the resource you can destruct all the ivars.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but sometimes we are bound by what we have to use (in my case Py_Finalize() and Py_XDECREF(object) for the context and the ivar code).